# String Comparison

Tags: arduino-ide, string

I am trying to compare two string but each time i am getting awkward results. When i use Equals() function i always get the wrong answer and never satisfy the IF statement. When i use compareTo() function i always get the right answer (which is btw not correct) but it always just satisfy the IF statement.

```cpp
String input;
String Answer = "cat";

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(19200);
}

void loop()
{
  while (Serial.available() == 0)
  {
    Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    if (input.equals(Answer))
    {
      Serial.println(input + ", Correct");
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println(input + ", wrong");
    }
  }
}
```

Above is the code i am using to learn the string Comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a variable named `input`, but you never assign a value
to it. It should thus always have its initial value, which is an empty
string.

Here:

```cpp
Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
```

you probably meant

```cpp
input = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
```

Comment: Edgar Bonet thanks. I have initialised the input as you mentioned. But results are same. I don't know what's getting wrong here.

Comment: @ASADALI, add `input.trim()` after `input = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');` to remove \r